# SQL Server Table Display Uncertainty

Tags: sql-server, database

In my database in the datatable I found some uncertainty while viewing the table. Rows are not sorted according to the id. I saw some random behavior. I mean the entire table should be there according to the Id. But it is not.

The snap of the datatable is[image]

Its not showing the entry as per the order it should be. I am selecting the top 11000 rows order by Id.

My query is

```
SELECT TOP 11000 [Id]
      ,[Date]
      ,[S11]
      ,[S12]
      ,[S13]
      ,[S14]
      ,[S15]
      ,[S21]
      ,[S22]
      ,[S23]
      ,[S24]
      ,[S25]
  FROM [MCAS].[dbo].[MCASMonitoring_Rev1] ORDER By Id
```

Why it is showing like this ?

Comment: try using `select top 11000 order by id desc` or try using `ranking functions`

Comment: i have ordered it by id only, it is showing perfect when I list it in the grid view in aspx page but the same query in sql server showing such results